# RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED

Tags: python, nlp

I am getting the below error

RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemmStridedBatched( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, stridea, b, ldb, strideb, &beta, c, ldc, stridec, num_batches)`

While executing the below code for extracting keyword using KeyBERT

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/3180169107.py in <module>
      3     key_list=kw_model.extract_keywords(text, keyphrase_ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words='english', use_mmr=True, diversity=0.7)
      4     return [key[0] for key in key_list]
----> 5 df_essays['Essay Text Extract Keyword']=df_essays['Essay Text'].apply(lambda x:keyword(x))
      6 df_essays.head()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwargs)
   4355         dtype: float64
   4356         """
-> 4357         return SeriesApply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, kwargs).apply()
   4358 
   4359     def _reduce(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply(self)
   1041             return self.apply_str()
   1042 
-> 1043         return self.apply_standard()
   1044 
   1045     def agg(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
   1099                     values,
   1100                     f,  # type: ignore[arg-type]
-> 1101                     convert=self.convert_dtype,
   1102                 )
   1103 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

/tmp/ipykernel_33/3180169107.py in <lambda>(x)
      3     key_list=kw_model.extract_keywords(text, keyphrase_ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words='english', use_mmr=True, diversity=0.7)
      4     return [key[0] for key in key_list]
----> 5 df_essays['Essay Text Extract Keyword']=df_essays['Essay Text'].apply(lambda x:keyword(x))
      6 df_essays.head()

/tmp/ipykernel_33/3180169107.py in keyword(text)
      1 def keyword(text):
      2     key_list=list()
----> 3     key_list=kw_model.extract_keywords(text, keyphrase_ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words='english', use_mmr=True, diversity=0.7)
      4     return [key[0] for key in key_list]
      5 df_essays['Essay Text Extract Keyword']=df_essays['Essay Text'].apply(lambda x:keyword(x))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keybert/_model.py in extract_keywords(self, docs, candidates, keyphrase_ngram_range, stop_words, top_n, min_df, use_maxsum, use_mmr, diversity, nr_candidates, vectorizer, highlight, seed_keywords)
    121                                                          nr_candidates=nr_candidates,
    122                                                          vectorizer=vectorizer,
--> 123                                                          seed_keywords=seed_keywords)
    124             if highlight:
    125                 highlight_document(docs, keywords)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keybert/_model.py in _extract_keywords_single_doc(self, doc, candidates, keyphrase_ngram_range, stop_words, top_n, use_maxsum, use_mmr, diversity, nr_candidates, vectorizer, seed_keywords)
    180 
    181             # Extract Embeddings
--> 182             doc_embedding = self.model.embed([doc])
    183             candidate_embeddings = self.model.embed(candidates)
    184 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keybert/backend/_sentencetransformers.py in embed(self, documents, verbose)
     51             that each have an embeddings size of `m`
     52         """
---> 53         embeddings = self.embedding_model.encode(documents, show_progress_bar=verbose)
     54         return embeddings

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py in encode(self, sentences, batch_size, show_progress_bar, output_value, convert_to_numpy, convert_to_tensor, device, normalize_embeddings)
    155 
    156             with torch.no_grad():
--> 157                 out_features = self.forward(features)
    158 
    159                 if output_value == 'token_embeddings':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
    117     def forward(self, input):
    118         for module in self:
--> 119             input = module(input)
    120         return input
    121 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sentence_transformers/models/Transformer.py in forward(self, features)
     49             trans_features['token_type_ids'] = features['token_type_ids']
     50 
---> 51         output_states = self.auto_model(**trans_features, return_dict=False)
     52         output_tokens = output_states[0]
     53 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids, position_ids, head_mask, inputs_embeds, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
   1004             output_attentions=output_attentions,
   1005             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
-> 1006             return_dict=return_dict,
   1007         )
   1008         sequence_output = encoder_outputs[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_values, use_cache, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    588                     encoder_attention_mask,
    589                     past_key_value,
--> 590                     output_attentions,
    591                 )
    592 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    473             head_mask,
    474             output_attentions=output_attentions,
--> 475             past_key_value=self_attn_past_key_value,
    476         )
    477         attention_output = self_attention_outputs[0]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    405             encoder_attention_mask,
    406             past_key_value,
--> 407             output_attentions,
    408         )
    409         attention_output = self.output(self_outputs[0], hidden_states)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    887             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    888         else:
--> 889             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    890         for hook in itertools.chain(
    891                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py in forward(self, hidden_states, attention_mask, head_mask, encoder_hidden_states, encoder_attention_mask, past_key_value, output_attentions)
    302 
    303         # Take the dot product between "query" and "key" to get the raw attention scores.
--> 304         attention_scores = torch.matmul(query_layer, key_layer.transpose(-1, -2))
    305 
    306         if self.position_embedding_type == "relative_key" or self.position_embedding_type == "relative_key_query":

RuntimeError: CUDA error: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED when calling `cublasSgemmStridedBatched( handle, opa, opb, m, n, k, &alpha, a, lda, stridea, b, ldb, strideb, &beta, c, ldc, stridec, num_batches)`
```

here is the code I have used

```
from keybert import KeyBERT
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
kw_model = KeyBERT(model=sentence_model)
def keyword(text):
    key_list=list()
    key_list=kw_model.extract_keywords(text, keyphrase_ngram_range=(3, 3), stop_words='english', use_mmr=True, diversity=0.7)
    return [key[0] for key in key_list]
df_essays['Essay Text Extract Keyword']=df_essays['Essay Text'].apply(lambda x:keyword(x))
df_essays.head()
```

Comment: Your error indicates that the function could not be executed on GPU. Do you have a GPU? Did you install all necessary CUDA libraries? Can/Did you already use the GPU for ML?

Comment: I just don't know I am trying to run code in Kaggle while turning on the GPU feature Whether I need to add any code for a specific CPU or GPU

Comment: Cuda is a package designed by Nvidia to take advantage of their GPU for data analysis. Without an Nvidia GPU, the correct drivers, and the actual Cuda package installed, you will get this error. Figure out what type of GPU you have and look into the other things I mentioned. You should be able to figure it out from there.